# Elastic search filter using query string

Tags: elasticsearch

Using Query string OnFieldWithBoosts added different fields need to apply filter, string fields records are working fine.

[image: Sample Code to fetch result]

For id field when I include **.Add(id,2)** it does not return ID based result.

When I use term then ID fields records working fine.
[image]

Now in the query section, 
I have used OR condition, so when first condition satisfies, it does not check second one.
If I user AND condition, then it checks for both the condition matches.

But I need first query results and second query results concat into one result

CODE:

```
           var result = client.Search<dynamic>(q => q
                        .Indices("test")
                        .Types("user")
                        .From(1)
                        .Size(10)
                        .MinScore(1.0)
                        .Fields("id", "createddate", "email", "modifieddate", "name", "companyname")  // Result set Fields Fields
                        .Query(q1 =>
                        {
                            qq = (q1.ConstantScore(a => a.Filter(b => b.Term("id", searchKeyword)))) 
                                || q1.QueryString(qs => qs.Query(searchKeyword).OnFieldsWithBoost(a => a.Add("notes",3).Add("email", 2).Add("name", 2)));                                
                            return qq;
                        })
                        );
```

Comment: Which Es version you are using?

Comment: Instead of writing in language code .Could you please write your ES query is question with your doubt ?

Comment: @VijayGupta Added my coding section

Comment: can you provide solution to search id based result using query string?